# Copy the nodes from the Chef Server

Tags: json, server, chef-infra, nodes, knife

Is there a way to access and the nodes(json files) in the Chef Server? 
I can see the nodes using "knife node list" and I am also able to modify them, but I would like to have the json files. 
I can see the ones on my local machine (chef zero) in this plae: ~/.chef/local-mode-default/nodes/

Answer (score 1):

`knife download nodes/` is what you are looking for.